# Ubuntu 13.04 64 Bits interface freezes when running videos on chrome, firefox and chromium

Tags: 13.04

Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit, interface freezes when running videos directly in the browser, leaving only the mouse pointer moving.

Behavior occurs with browsers Google Chrome, Chromium and Firefox.

My hardware:

> Intel Pentium Dual Core G860
>
> Integrated video processor (Intel HD2000)
>
> Motherboard Asus P8H61-M LE BR
>
> 4GB DDR3 Dual Channel

I think something on the flash.

Answer (score 0):

I installed flashplayer through synaptic on my Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit and installed flashplugin-installer, my firefox (version 22.0) also freeze for awhile everytime streaming from youtube, but chrome is working fine. Then I follow instruction below :
http://ubuntuguide.net/install-adobe-flash-plugin-in-ubuntu-12-04both-3264-bit
it work okay now, the freezing problem were gone !

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem on ubuntu 13.04, and it solved after i uninstall unity-webapps-facebookapps and unity-webapps-youtube

Answer (score -2):

There was, literally just within the past few hours, an update to adobe flash player package.

Try doing..

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

.. and see if you see the updates come through.  If so, that may fix your problem.  If NOT, it's possible the update may have caused the issue and we can continue troubleshooting at that point.

Good luck, and let us know what you find!

EDIT: Also, within the past hour there's been a Firefox update.  You may want to run this and get a list of what packages you update and make note if they cumulatively resolve the issues.